# Gembox get count of all rows (including blank) of specfic column

Tags: gembox-spreadsheet

I am trying to get count of last used row for a specific column, but was only able to get count of max rows occupied. Test data is shown in attached snap. Please help. [Snap Attached Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H7k0.jpg)

```
        SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
        ExcelFile ef = ExcelFile.Load("test.xlsx");

        CellRange rcount = ef.Worksheets[0].Columns[1].Cells;
        Console.WriteLine(ef.Worksheets[0].Rows.Count);


        ef.Save("test.xlsx");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells are internally allocated in rows, not in columns. In other words, you could get the last used column for each row with `ExcelRow.AllocatedCells.Count`.

For getting the last used row in a specific column you can use something like the following:

```cs
ExcelFile ef = ExcelFile.Load("test.xlsx");
ExcelWorksheet ws = ef.Worksheets[0];

ExcelColumn column = ws.Columns[1];
int rowIndex = ws.Rows.Count - 1;

while (rowIndex >= 0 && column.Cells[rowIndex].ValueType == CellValueType.Null)
    --rowIndex;

Console.WriteLine(rowIndex);
```

I hope this helps.